# IPSec and traffic mirroring

Tags: ipsec, iptables, voip

I have a VoIP server on which several SIP clients are connected to through IPSec tunnels.
This is kind of an automated attendant so I both have RTP and SIP signalling flows.

I need to be able to store all RTP traffic on another server for recording purposes.

Is it possible, using iptables and the TEE option, to mirror RTP trafic only and send it, through another IPSec tunnel, towards the recording server?